# JQuery - How to detect if a div includes a special position

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have 2 divs like 
`<div class="parent"<div class="child"></div></div>`.
First I need to know the horizontal center of the "parent" div.

```
var offset = $('.parent').offset(),
    width = $('.parent').width(),
    parentCenter = offset.left + width / 2;
```

Now, I need to know if the "child" div passes or includes this position.
Example: The parent div is a wrapper and the child div is a image that should be bigger if it passes the center of the parent. (the child is moveable by a slide effect)

Comment: what do you mean by "if the "child" div passes or includes this position"?

Comment: So if the absolute X/Y Coordinates of `<div class="child" />` are within the `<div class="parent" />`?

Comment: use the .position() function to get the offset of an element relative to its parent

Comment: I have the horizontal Center of the parent div and I want to detect when the child enter this position like: if(child.hasPosition(parentCenter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child will intersect with that position if its left corner is further left AND the right corner is further right than the position you already calculated:

```
var child = $('#child');

// Get X coordinates of child's corners
var leftX = child.offset().left;
var rightX = leftX + child.width();

if (leftX <= parentCenter && parentCenter <= rightX) {
    // child overlaps with parent's center (on the X axis)
}
```